# Use Principal Axis Optimizer for constrained Problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The "Principal Axis" Optimizer described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationPrincipalAxisMethod.html) works particuarly well on my problem. Now I do know some constraints about my problem and would like to implement them to make it faster. Even though it is an unconstrained optimizer it performs better without specified constraints than the other constrained optimizers with specified constraints.
Mathematica forbids to specify constraints for this particular method. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Adding a penalty function to the objective function is common method.  I believe *Mathematica* often (always?) imposes constraints by such a method.

Comment: Of course I can add a penalty function to introduce constraints. But I have  constraints of the form $3 < x < 10$. I would like to tell the Principal Axis Optimizer that it doesn't need to check all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. With this I hope to make it more efficient at solving my problem.